# При клике на область dom-элемента не появляется окошечко

Tags: jquery, dom, append, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Функционал требует без обновления страницы добавить в конец списка новый элемент, у него есть область задания цвета - цветной круг при клике, рядом с ним должно появляться окошечко выбора цвета.

Проблема в том, что на всех появляется, а вот именно на добавленном элементе - нет. Что делать?

Вот код для появления элемента:

```
    // При наведении на ссылку
    $('.color-status').bind('click', function () {

    // Получаем ID блока, который нужно показать
    var title = $(this).data("target");

    // Показываем блок
    $(this).after($(title));
    $(title).slideDown(500);
    });
    // При уходе мышки со ссылки
    $('.close-color').bind('click', function () {

    // Получаем ID блока, который нужно показать
    // Скрываем блок
    $('#color-picker').slideUp(500);

    }); 
                                $('.block_open_botton').bind('click', function () {

    $("#table-ul").append('<li data-statusid=50>...</li>');

});
```

Что делать в этом случае?

Answer (score 1):

В этом случае надо читать [документацию](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

> Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those **elements must exist at the point the call to .bind() occurs**.

И решение там же:

> For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().

Comment: Ты, конечно, молодец! Но решение бы, =/ в английском слабоват.

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev, будем считать, что я испугался вашего минуса и погуглил для вас:

[Не работает событие, привязанное к элементу, созданному первым событием](http://hashcode.ru/questions/330554/jquery-не-работает-событие-привязанное-к-элементу-созданному-первым-событием)

Comment: Т.е. надо писать еще одно дополнительное событие клик?

Comment: Все равно не понял, как мне надо сделать в моем случае...